# PowerShell Move-Item - Not Moving Files

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a script (pasted below) that's supposed to do the following:

1. Loops and grabs all files that match a defined pattern
2. Copies those files into another location
3. Move the original source file into another location (if copy was successful)

It's doing step #1 and #2 but step #3, Move-Item is not moving any files and I don't know why and I get no indication of an error

Can someone help? Thanks

```
$source = "C:\Users\Tom\"
$source_move = "C:\Users\Tom\OldLogBackup1\"
$destination ="C:\Users\Tom\Mirror\"

if(-not(Test-Path $destination)){mkdir $destination | out-null}


ForEach ($sourcefile In $(Get-ChildItem $source | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "Daily_Reviews\[\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d\].journal" }))
{
    #escape filename because there are brackets in the name!
$src = [Management.Automation.WildcardPattern]::Escape($sourcefile)
Copy-Item  $src $destination

### Check for a successful file copy
if($?)
{

    #### 
    if(-not(Test-Path $source_move)){
        echo "Path does not exist!"
    } else { 
        echo "Path exists!"

        ### Move original source file someplace else
        Move-Item $source_move$sourcefile $source_move
        if($?)
        {
            echo "Source file successfully moved"

        } else {

            echo "Source file was not successfully moved"

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try along with the `-force` option.

Answer (score 0):

The line `Move-Item $source_move$sourcefile $source_move` is moving the `$sourcefile` in the `$source_move` directory to the `$source_move` directory, which does nothing. I am guessing you meant to do `Move-Item $source$sourcefile $source_move`, or `Move-Item $src $source_move`.

Also, `echo` is simply an alias for [`Write-Output`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113427), which returns the argument to the caller. You can achieve the same result without the echo (any object on its own will be returned). Or, if you intended to use these as debug statements, you could use [`Write-Debug`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113424) or [`Write-Host`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113426).